# Showing that the $p$-norm converges in $\mathbb{R}$ as $p\to \infty$

Tags: analysis

I've been asked to show that $(\|x\|_p)_{p \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ as $p\to \infty$.

My idea is to consider balls of the form: $$B_{p_i} := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|_{p_i} < \epsilon \}$$ Since $B_{p_1} \subset B_{p_2} \subset ...$ for $p_1 < p_2 < ...$ (how do I show this without just using a diagram as 'proof'?), $x \in B_{p_1} \implies x \in B_{p_2}$ and so for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have: $$|\|x\|_{p_1} - \|x\|_{p_2}| < 2\epsilon$$ for all $x \in B_{p_1}$. Can I then just say that this is true for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ since any x chosen lies in another open ball of some radius $\epsilon$?

Sorry if this is totally wrong. I don't know exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Is it bounded? Is it monotone?

Comment: Edit puting something like this: "For each $x\in \Bbb R$ the sequence .........is convergent" (in your sequence $x$ is fixed and it is $p$ the variable)..

Comment: I understand. So is my approach correct?

Comment: "Since $B_{p_1} \subset B_{p_2}$ for $p_1 < p_2$, $x \in B_{p_1} \implies x \in B_{p_2}$ and so for any $\epsilon > 0$: $|\|x\|_{p_1} - \|x\|_{p_2}| < 2\epsilon$ for all $x \in B_{p_1}$." What? How is the inclusion $B_{p_1} \subset B_{p_2}$ supposed to imply the inequality $|\|x\|_{p_1} - \|x\|_{p_2}| < 2\epsilon$?

Comment: In this exercise you should think of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ as fixed and of $p$ as the norm-indexed tending to infinity.  The limit exists (as you are asked to show).  Try the case $n=2$ as a starter to get the idea.